# Div stretches when it is refreshed by a timed javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div which is set to refresh every 5s via a javascript reload. WHen the main page loads it is fine, it fits in it's box and everything is in line (picture 1). After 5s when the javascript reloads it, it stretches the div (picture 2) and after another 5s it stretches again (image 3) it then remains at this level of stretch. I've tried putting the div with id=messages as class=col_1_2 one but it make no difference.

[image: Picture 1 - before the reload]

[image: Picture 1 - after the first reload]

[image: Picture 2 - after subsequent reloads]

index.php - where the div is:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="clear padding20"></div>
<div class="col_1_2"><?php include('companynews.php'); ?></div>
<div class="col_1_2 last" id="messagesouter" name="messagesouter"><div id="messages" class="messages"><?php include('messages.php'); ?></div></div>
<div class="clear padding20"></div>
 <div class="container">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-0">Employee Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Abscence Records</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Fleet Records</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Time Sheets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Abscence Request</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="bordered_box"></div>
more of the page
```

Javascript to reload the messages div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadlink(){
    $('#messages').load('messages.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); 
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() 
}, 5000);
</script>
```

CSS for the class:

```
.col_1_2 {
    width:460px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
```

example output of messages.php:

```
<div class="toogle_box">
      <div class="toggle opened_toggle">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        Messages </div>
      <div class="toggle_container">
      <!--LINE MANAGER ONLY ITEMS-->
            <!--PENDING ABSCENCE REQUESTS-->
      You have 1 pending abscence request<br>
    <!--TIMESHEETS TO BE COMPLETED-->
    Please complete the timesheet for 01/12/2015<br>Please complete the timesheet for 02/12/2015<br>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the response from the server when you make that ajax call?

Comment: I guess the javascript you provided is not enough to spot the issue. What is an example output from messages.php?

Comment: I've added a sample output of messages.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using some CSS framework (Bootstrap?) in your layout, namely `.col_1_2`.

When you use the jQuery `.load()` method, you are getting your content from `message.php`, which is okay.

However, after the load is finished, you issue `$(this).unwrap()` which removes the parent element that is enclosing `#messages`, first the block with classes `col_1_2 last` and then upon the another load, the block with class `container`.

The code is systematically undoing the layout parent block by parent block.

I don't think you need the `.unwrap()` method, so try removing it.